# Magento 2 Speed Optimization: default component/events taking too long to load like routers_match taking around 6sec

Tags: profiler, speedoptimization

I have setup a magento store:

**Server Details:**
AWS EC2 instance: c4.2xlarge(Region: us-west-1c)
AWS RDS instance: db.t2.xlarge(Region: us-west-1c)

**Store Details:**
Magento Version: 2.3.1
Theme Installed: AutoStore - Auto Parts and Equipments (from https://themeforest.net)
Total number of products in my site: 360,000 products

I am working on the speed optimization of its pages and getting 40sec TTFB, so to improve that **I have enabled Magento 2 default profiler.**

I got to know that there is unusual time taken by events/components of default Magento like:

**On product detail page:**
 load_entities is taking around 8sec http://prntscr.com/rj0949 
And, on enabling Magento 2 default function for current product stock qty taking around 14 sec.

**On product cart page:**
 session_start is taking around 6sec http://prntscr.com/rj0mhv

Finding solution to improve time of those default component time as much as possible. Is there any way for this.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have varnish and redis with session lock enabled?

Comment: upgrade magento and theme to 2.3.4 and start testing again

Comment: I have enabled varnish on the store.